# DHARMa diagnostics: testDispersion and testZeroInflation interpretation

Tags: count-data, zero-inflation, diagnostic, overdispersion, glmmtmb

I have been analyzing count data using Poisson distribution in glmmTMB, and just ran some DHARMA diagnostics. However, there don't seem to be a lot of help online on how to interpret the results. Does the left graph indicate underdispersion? And if the red line is all the way to the right - is it overdispersion?

And does the right graph show that there is no zero inflation? 
When running `zero_count(model1)` from sjstats, the result indicates that the model is overfitting zero counts - meaning no zero inflation?

[image: Dispersion and zero inflation tests]

Answer (score 2):

The left hand plot shows your actual dispersion with a histogram of simulated residuals. Since your value is to the left it indicates that your model has under-dispersion. The right hand plot shows the simulated number of zeroes with your actual number shown as red. You have fewer zeroes than expected.