# Logistic Regression Residual Analysis in R (replicate influence command from SAS)

Tags: r, logistic, residuals, sas

I'm looking for a quick reference on how to do some residual analysis for logistic regression in R. Oddly enough, this has not been easy to find.

The data set I am working with is the Add.dat which can be found here: https://www.uvm.edu/~dhowell/fundamentals9/DataFiles/

Once imported I had to convert the binary variables to factors:

```
cols <- c(3, 4, 9, 10)
Add[,cols] <- lapply(Add[, cols], factor)
```

The model I'm using is very simple:

```
glm(formula = Repeat ~ ADDSC, family = binomial, data = Add)
```

I have several questions that should be relatively straight forward for the experienced:

1. How do I find the leverage of the predictor variable?
2. How do I find Cook's distance (namely, the cooks.distance function does seem to work for glm according to the help file, but I would just like validation of that)?
3. How do I find the dfBeta values for the slope?
4. Similarly, is there a way to get the delta chi-square/delta deviance for the observations?

Also, what is a good way of graphing the pearson residuals?

In short, I am basically looking to replicate the output of adding the influence command in SAS for logistic regression.

Comment: You can take ideas from:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/398817/conditions-in-which-the-sign-of-a-coefficient-will-change-between-a-linear-proba,   https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/406860/dharma-diagnostics-testdispersion-and-testzeroinflation-interpretation, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/436481/how-to-interpret-quantile-residuals   look into the R `DHARMa` package.

Comment: Thanks for this resource. I'm working through it now. It's very cool and surprisingly intuitive. I am going to use this, but, that said, this doesn't (so far as I can tell) answer my questions. The reason I need direct answers is because I'm specifically trying to replicate what SAS is doing in helping a professor of mine, and I obviously don't want to get it wrong. I will, however, also work through dharma and show it to her as well.

Comment: I don't know about sas, so some other must answer that. I added the [tag:sas] tag so people interested in that can see it.

Comment: I was debating that myself. Probably the best idea. Thank you.